# can vs could difference

Tags: modal-verbs

1. The most we **can** expect is a slight cut in the sales-tax. (this is what is reasonable or acceptable)
2. With a new wind generation record of 4,131 megawatts set on 14 September, the question of how far the UK's wind generation fleet can help in meeting our climate targets is increasingly controversial. Now it **can** be shown that the sceptics who lobby against wind simply have their facts wrong.(https://www.theguardian.com/environment/blog/2012/sep/26/myth-wind-turbines-carbon-emissions)

Can I use "could" in place of "can" in (1) and (2)? If so, does it change the meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of "could" in place of "can"in these sorts of constructions  generally implies something that might happen, but has not not happened yet. Use of "can" tends to imply something that will or probably will happen.

In (1) "could is grammatical, but implies a greater doubt than "can" does. "The most we can expect" indicates something that is plausible, even likely, but not assured. However,  "The most we could expect" indicates somethign that is possible, but not likely.

In (2) "far the UK's wind generation fleet could help " suggests greater doubt as to whether that help will be achieved than "can" does. But since the original using can is already6 questioning the outcome, the meaning is not very different. Changing "Now it can be shown" to "Now it could be shown" implies that such a demonstration would be possible ut has not yet been worked out. Again in thi9s particular text, the change of meaning is not large.